# what memory is displayed in the logged message

Tags: memory, grails, out-of-memory, heap-memory, java-melody

I noticed when I run a big job in my grails application (that reads huge amounts of data from db) I have this log(no idea what generates the log, maybe the melody plugin?): `Memory usage: used=588MB free=14MB total=683MB` in the console and soon I receive:

`Exception in thread "http-nio-8180-AsyncTimeout" Exception in thread "http-nio-8180-ClientPoller-1" Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`,

even though the heap memory seems to have much more memory left as displayed in intellij:
[image].

Also, starting the application I explicitly added JVM params:-`Xmx40968m -Xms2048m`.

On what type of memory do I run low?

Comment: Is that memory meter (1484 of 5916M) measuring the process that is running out of memory, or measuring the process your IDE is running in (or both)?

Comment: It is either the memory used by the application or by Inteliji. The memory  logged in the console refers to some other memory because it says: total=683MB

Comment: "It is either the memory used by the application or by Inteliji." - Those are 2 different things of course.  Do you know if it is the intellij memory or your app memory?  It isn't obvious from the screenshot.